# Add collections form into DomCrawler

Tags: symfony, goutte

Form now, when i want to make functional testing on a form i am doing this was :

```
$crawler = $this->client->submit($form, array(
        'type[category]'  => 'foo',
        'type[administrable]'  => '1',
    ));
```

I thought that to add collections form i ad to do this way :

```
$crawler = $this->client->submit($form, array(
        'type[fields][0][length]'  => '5',
        'type[fields][0][search]'  => '1',
        'type[fields][0][required]'  => '1',
    ));
```

But it's not working!

Does DomCrawler/Goutte support Collection or it there a specific way to deal with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sounds like it's an open bug :

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/4124